# Is there a (Riemann) explicit formula for $\sum_{p\le x}\frac{1}{p}$ involving a sum over the non-trivial zeros ρ of the Riemann zeta function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $f(x)=\sum_{p\le x}\frac{1}{p}$ and $f_0(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x+0)+f(x-0))$. Then is there a (Riemann) explicit formula for $f_0(x)$ involving a sum over the non-trivial zeros ρ of the Riemann zeta function?

Comment: What is a "(Riemann) explicit formula"?

Comment: @LSpice A formula for $f_0(x)$ which is similar to 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)

Comment: What do you get from $\sum_p p^{-1} = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{\mu(k)}{k} \sum_{p^m \le x} \frac{p^{-mk}}{m}$